# Security concerns about the use of client-side API_KEY

Tags: javascript, security, browser, client, getstream-io

I'm new using getstream-io and currently in the first steps of the development of chat using getstream using the React API.

As per documentation I see that for intialize a chat client we need to create a StreamChat using:

```
const client = new StreamChat(MY_API_KEY);

// example: const client = new StreamChat("qk4nn7rpcn75");
```

I'm thinking if it's safe in terms of security to bring this API_KEY available in the UI-browser because this apikey could be took from browser and reuse without any restrictions.

The question is, it's safe to let this API_KEY available in the UI-browser?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's safe and actually it will be passed as a query parameter in each request for easier visibility in logs. To better understand, you can think `key` as your user name and `secret` as your password.

In this mode (client-side auth), client isn't functional yet, you will need to set a user token signed by your secret. However, revealing that token or your secret isn't secure:

- `token`: your user can be impersonated
- `secret`: anything is possible